# No puedo obtener id de registro en una tabla html con javascript

Tags: jquery, html5

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
document.querySelector("#resultado").addEventListener("click", 
      function(event){
         var id= $(this).find("tr").html();   
        alert(id);

                    }, false);
      });
```

pero no logro obtener el id. Se trata de una tabla de productos y la primer columna es el idproducto. Trabajo con MVC por lo que se crea dinamicamente.
Luego de obtener el id y la cantidad lo agregare a un detalle de ticket pero eso despues.

el html creado desde php es:

```html
        $arrayfiltrado=$P1->filtrar($tipoFiltro,$cadena);
     $tabla ="<caption> CATALOGO DE ARTICULOS</caption>

<tr> <th>COD.:</th> <th>DESCRIPCION</th> <th>MARCA</th>
<th>CATEGORIA</th> <th>P/U</th>
</tr>";
       /* No olvide el THEAD y sus TD para formar el encabezado de la tabla */
       /* Contenido de la tabla */
       $tabla .="<tbody>";
       foreach ($arrayfiltrado as $p){
          $tabla .="<tr>";
             /* Un TD por cada datos que quieras mostrar; emj con el mail */
             $tabla .="<td>".$p["idproducto"]."</td>";
             $tabla .="<td>".$p["nombre"]."</td>";
             $tabla .="<td>".$p["marca"]."</td>";
             $tabla .="<td>".$p["categoria"]."</td>";
             $tabla .="<td>".$p["precio"]."</td>";
          $tabla .="</tr>";
       }
       $tabla .="</tbody>";
       $tabla .="</table>";
       echo $tabla;
           }}
```

Comment: Hola @user3780282, ¿podrías añadir al código HTML?

Comment: No veo el id `#resultado` en tu HTML.  Lo que quieres es obtener el valor de `idproducto`?

Comment: Claro en la pagina principal tengo un table cuyo id es resultado donde va el echo de la tabla que se ve ahi.

Comment: ¿A qué elemento del DOM le estás danto el id="resultado"?

Comment: tengo un <table id="resultado"> osea del tipo table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin ver la estructura de tu HTML es un poco mas dificil, pero lo puedes hacer asi:

```js
$("#resultado tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
     var id= $(this).find("td:first-child").html();   
     alert(id);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="resultado">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>peras</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>manzanas</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Osea el id que le pasas a attr? Cada <tr> debe tener un valor en id para que sea devuelto?

Comment: Depende de lo que quieras obtener, yo pense que querias obtener el id del <tr>.  Que es exactamente lo que quieres obtener?

Comment: quiero obtener el id del producto para ponerlo en el detalle del ticket o factura

Comment: Quieres obtener solo el primer id, o como deseas obtener un id especifico?

Comment: la idea es seleccionar el producto de la tabla mediante un click en cualquiera..para eso necesito al hacer click obtener el id pero del producto en cuestion. Del que se hizo click

Comment: ya edite mi respuesta, intentalo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77536/discussion-between-alanfcm-and-caruso).

Answer (score 0):

Estás mezclando dos cosas, javascript puro con la librería de jQuery. Deberías agregar la [librería](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js) primero de jQuery al html y luego cambiar el evento por el de jQuery.

```
$("#resultado").click(function(event) {
  var id = $(this).find("tr").html();   
  alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que lo que quieres es obtener el ID de la fila donde clicas, aunque tu post es un poco confuso.

```
// Detectar clic en una fila
$('#resultado tr').click(() => {
    // Obtener el texto de la primera celda de la fila que es el ID
    let id = $(this).find('td:first-child').text();
    // Mostrar alert con el ID obtenido
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Gracias a vos tambien por la respuesta..no me devuelve ningun alert. Si hago: `código`$('#resultado').click(() => {
    // Obtener el texto de la primera celda de la fila que es el ID
    let id = $(this).find('td:first-child').text();
    // Mostrar alert con el ID obtenido
    alert(id);
}); `código`me devuelve todo los id juntos en el alert. pero porque asi como me pasaste no funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno el error estaba en el DOM. Es decir no estaba creando la etiqueta body del table..
lo correcto es asi:

```html
<table id="resultado">
<thead>
<tr> <th>COD.:</th> <th>DESCRIPCION</th> <th>MARCA</th>
            <th>CATEGORIA</th> <th>P/U</th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody>
            
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Igua si uso "" dinamicamente, es decir el que crea Jquery con el JSON este no funciona para recorrer la tabla, entonces el codigo que me quedo es el siguiente:

```js
$("#resultado tbody").click(function(event) {
  $("tr").click(function(event) {
  var id = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
 alert(id);

});
```

en el evento ready de document. Igual voy a dejar un checkbox en cada fila, que tambien se marque al hacer click en cualquier lugar de la misma.